# Why is the database used by Django subqueries not sticky?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a concern with django subqueries using the django ORM. When we fetch a queryset or perform a DB operation, I have the option of bypassing all assumptions that django might make for the database that needs to be used by forcing usage of the specific database that I want.

```
b_det = Book.objects.using('some_db').filter(book_name = 'Mark')
```

The above disregards any database routers I might have set and goes straight to 'some_db'.

But if my models approximately look like so :-

```
class Author(models.Model):
    author_name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author_address=models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Book(models.Model):
    book_name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author=models.ForeignKey(Author, null = True)
```

And I fetch a QuerySet representing all books that are called Mark like so:-

```
b_det = Book.objects.using('some_db').filter(book_name = 'Mark')
```

Then later if somewhere in the code I trigger a subquery by doing something like:-

```
if b_det:
    auth_address = b_det[0].author.author_address
```

Then this does not make use of the original database 'some_db' that I had specified early on for the main query. This again goes through the routers and picks up (possibly) the incorrect database.

Why does django do this. IMHO , if I had selected forced usage of database for the original query then even for the subquery the same database needs to be used. Why must the database routers come into picture for this at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a subquery in the strict SQL sense of the word. What you are actually doing here is to execute one query and use the result of that to find related items.

You can chain filters and do lots of other operations on a queryset but it will not be executed until you take a slice on it or call .values() but here you are actually taking a slice

```
auth_address = b_det[0].#rest of code
```

So you have a materialized query and you are now trying to find the address of the related author and that requires another query but you are not using with so django is free to choose which database to use. You cacn overcome this by using [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related)

Comment: I don't think using select_related is an option at all since I do not know beforehand what inner joins I might need to execute. In my implementation there are 6 levels of tables referenced using foreign keys. If I put everything in select_related, it would become one massive query every time.

Comment: Six different queries were not mentioned in your question. What I have answered is your original question.

Comment: Ok the select_related is one way to get around the problem.